# How do I merge when one commit includes the changes from another commit?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a project that's using git. When I received the repo, it had some uncommitted changes. I committed those, and started making my own.

I received work from another developer, and that developer committed both their changes and the **original uncommitted changes** into a single commit.

Now I have two git repos in separate folders and I'd like to know how I can merge my changes into the developers changes with as few conflicts as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your tip currently checked out, and it is `master`, one option would be to:
 1. [Add a remote](http://help.github.com/remotes/) from your repository pointing to theirs. 
 2. Fetch in his changes
`git fetch hisRemote`
 
 2. Then create a new branch with only the changes you made, that is branched off of where you committed the original changes.  
`git branch myChanges`
 3. Reset the `master` branch back to the commit where you committed the original changed 
`git checkout master`
`git reset --hard <commitOriginalChangesAreIn>`
 4. Then merge his branch with his changes and the original changes into that branch.
`git merge hisRemoteBranch`
 5. Finally merge that branch tip into the branch with your changes.
`git merge myChanges`

Comment: One question is when I run `git fetch hisRemote` my master branch gets overwritten with the other devs changes. Is this supposed to happen? (My work is on a separate branch.) Because when I get to step 3, I am essentially undoing all the changes I'm importing.

Comment: The fetch shouldn't overwrite any local branches. Are you sure it is?